# error in parsing a xml in android

Tags: android

I have a problem in parsing xml in android. I want to pick specific country. When user taps on that country tags of that specific country should appear...Can anyone guide me? I have done r and d. Also implemented parsing. But the issue is that countries get repeated.. If anyone can tell, what to do for specific country.

Here is the url
http://www.harpreetvirk.com/PMEvents/PMe.svc/providers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should change the question to "parsing xml from an url"

Comment: need more clarification as exactly what you want? which parser have you implemented?

Comment: @DagW okkk,,,i am using sax parser....

Comment: Simple is that..
if you are trying to fetch specific country detail then there MUST be only one record per country.

but you are getting many records from the url say for CANADA so how can you determine to get which record. and if this is your question then how can anyone give solution to you? please read your question and make it clear.

Comment: @Frankenstein ok,,,my question is  if you are trying to fetch specific country detail then there MUST be only one record per country. but you are getting many records from the url say for CANADA,,There are many records for a particular country,,,u can see,,by hitting

Answer (score 0):

What parser are you using? Try this one..
this walks through an xmldocument from an inputsream
This example is bad for multiple tags with the same name, but you could use it as a base

```
public HashMap<String, String> receiveXml(InputStream is)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    factory.setValidating(false);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

    xpp.setInput(is, "UTF-8");

    String parent = "";
    String collect = "";

    HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            // Start Document
            if (xpp.getName() != null)
                mymap.put(xpp.getName().toLowerCase(), "tag");
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            // Start tag
            // Parent name
            if (xpp.getName() != null) {
                collect += "<" + xpp.getName() + ">";
                mymap.put(xpp.getName().toLowerCase(), "tag");
                parent = xpp.getName().toLowerCase();
            }
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            // End tag
            if(xpp.getName()!=null)
                collect += "</" + xpp.getName() + ">";
            if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("PG"))
                break;
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            // Innehåll
            collect += xpp.getText();
            mymap.put(parent, xpp.getText());
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    // End Document
    mymap.put("string", collect);
    return mymap;
};
```